# How can I get an output of both decimal and whole number?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a Fahrenheit to Celsius conversion. I have it set to 2 decimal points as the output but lets say a user enters 50, it will come out as 10.00. How can I get it to come out as 10 without decimal, but allow decimal when it isn't a whole number?

```
temp = float(input(" Fahrenheit temperature: "))
celsius = float((5/9)*(temp - 32))
print("The temperature in celsius is: {:.2f}°.".format(celsius))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
temp = float(input(" Fahrenheit temperature: "))
celsius = float((5/9)*(temp - 32))
if (celsius % 1 == 0):
    print("The temperature in celsius is: {}°.".format(celsius))
else:
    print("The temperature in celsius is: {:.2f}°.".format(celsius))
```

The `if` condition checks whether or not you have a whole number.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this separately, because what counts as "close enough" to 50 to display as 50 is application-specific.

```
if abs(celsius % 1) < 0.001  # Or whatever threshold you want:
    print("The temperature in celsius is: {:d}°.".format(int(celsius//1)))
else:
    print("The temperature in celsius is: {:.2f}°.".format(celsius))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
def doTheThing(number):
    numString = str(number)
    i = len(numString) -1
    while True:
        if numString[i] == ".":
            numString = numString[:-1] #remove the .
            break
        if numString[i] == "0":
            numString = numString[:-1] #remove the 0
        else:
            break
        i-=1
    print(numString)



x = 10.0
doTheThing(x)
```

This will print 10, where as regular print will return 10.0

There is probably a better way but this works ;)

Answer (score -2):

You could try casting celsius to an int while you print it:

```
print("The temperature in celsius is :{:.2f}°.".format(int(celsius)))
```

Comment: That will truncate *any* fractional part of `celsius`.

Comment: Oh your right, they would probably have to add an if statement that looks for leading zeros then.